# How do I configure metric beat to report disk errors?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, disk, metricbeat

The journald log is reporting:

```
Jul 22 09:39:26 zora kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#14 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jul 22 09:39:26 zora kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#14 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Jul 22 09:39:26 zora kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#14 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
Jul 22 09:39:26 zora kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#14 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 6a 35 61 50 00 00 02 60 00 00
```

Are there any MetricBeat modules that can be used to report this? I'd like to get a report on the number of disk errors over a period of time.

Thanks!